# Accessing activatedRoute.params for service

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular Project that uses a lot of path parameters

```
/sec/:sec/subsec/:subsec/foo/:foo
```

this of course is also being use by the back end API so I need to access them, this is starting to create a bit of a tangled mess.  At present I am using `activatedRoute` in my components to gain access to these parameters.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
this.sec = params['sec'];
```

However, this is leading to me creating the exact same code over and over in every component. I would very much like to simple create a service that allows me to access these parameters, for example:

```
    class myParamState{

    sec: string;
    subsec: string
    foo: string;
    //...

    }
```

At this point I have managed to gain access to the router in my router outlet component, this almost does it for me.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe(val => {
console.log(val);
});
}
```

Where am I stuck? I am unsure how to extract parameters from the router (not even sure if this is the best approach). If I could I would be able to just update a service I can reuse, and I would be done.

I feel like I am missing something very obvious,maybe something built in ― I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

I think the good aproach in this situation is to create converter service which takes params and convert it to your model (myParamState). After conversion you can pass this object to another service and send it to backend.